# convert document to google format using google.apps.scritp

Tags: google-apps-script, type-conversion, document

I can't find the way to convert the documents uploaded by my google script into the native Google Docs format.

In Drive configuration options, you can set if the uploaded document will convert automatically into Google Docs format. But when i do this in my google apps sript with the DocList.createFile() method, the convertion is not maked.

This is my script

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload CSV to Sheet");
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  // display a confirmation message
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
  app.add(label);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this is possible as of today. Seeing that DocsList is "experimental," it's probably missing features that will be rolling out soon enough. So just keep an eye out for it.